# Custom colors in the modeline for a specific minor mode

Tags: emacs, configuration, fonts, colors

Purely for eye candy reasons I'd like to have one minor mode to be shown in the modeline has '((()))'   (without the single quotes).

It's for the `rainbow-delimiters-mode`.  So far I got the following in my *.emacs* and it works:

```
(setq minor-mode-alist (cons '(rainbow-delimiters-mode " ((()))") minor-mode-alist))
```

However now I'd like to be using three different colors inside the modeline so that the parentheses in my modeline "reflect" what the rainbow-delimiters-mode does.

How should I go about it?  (I don't care about the colors matching the actual colors `rainbow-delimiters-mode` is using)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, so the question is: "How to get different text colors within the mode line?"

Comment: @Dualinity: different colors for different characters each describing the same minor-mode : )    I can already assign, say, a color to one minor-mode (eg Paredit) in the modeline, but I don't know how to do this for each character of a single minor mode.

Comment: Sounds like a really specific small thing. Though if I would have to bet that any program could, Emacs would be the choice :P Now you just need some Emacs wizard...

Comment: Does the answer I provided work for you? Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: @user4815162342: nice nick ; )    Answer works fine.  +1 and accepted.   Thanks for the explanation : )

Comment: You're welcome; enjoy the power of Emacs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it, tested in Emacs 24.2.1:

```
(setq minor-mode-alist
      `((rainbow-delimiters-mode " ")
        (rainbow-delimiters-mode #("(" 0 1 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face)))
        (rainbow-delimiters-mode #("(" 0 1 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-2-face)))
        (rainbow-delimiters-mode #("(" 0 1 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face)))
        (rainbow-delimiters-mode #(")" 0 1 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face)))
        (rainbow-delimiters-mode #(")" 0 1 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-2-face)))
        (rainbow-delimiters-mode #(")" 0 1 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face)))
        ,@(assq-delete-all 'rainbow-delimiters-mode minor-mode-alist)))
```

It makes use of string properties to add colors to the minor mode indicator—the `#("(" 0 1 (face foo-face))"` syntax specifies a one-character string with the `face` property set to `foo-face` for the range [0, 1).

Since a string can have many properties, one would expect to be able to specify a single `minor-mode-alist` entry with different faces for each character. However, due to what is presumably an Emacs bug, only the properties of the first character of the minor mode indicator are respected when displaying the mode line. To work around this, the code makes use of the fact that Emacs merges multiple `minor-mode-alist` indicators for the same mode. It specifies several strings, each of its own color, for `rainbow-delimiters-mode`, and uses `assq-delete-all` to remove old rainbow delimiter entries from `minor-mode-alist`.

For completeness, here is the single-entry code, which appears colorless in Emacs 24.2.1 because its first character doesn't specify a face:

```
(setq minor-mode-alist
      `((rainbow-delimiters-mode #(" ((()))"
                                   1 2 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face)
                                   2 3 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-2-face)
                                   3 4 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face)
                                   4 5 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-3-face)
                                   5 6 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-2-face)
                                   6 7 (face rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face)))
        ,@(assq-delete-all 'rainbow-delimiters-mode minor-mode-alist)))
```